# How to scroll to top in Stack Exchange Android app?

Tags: feature-request, status-completed, android-app

As depicted in below picture, I have scrolled down to 5-10 pages and now what if I would like to scroll to top? **Instant/fast scroll to top** should be there.

[image]

Comment: Absolutely agreed, we just haven't found a good way to do it.

Comment: @balpha BTW here is technical solution :) programmer of this app could enable [android:fastScrollEnabled](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/AbsListView.html#attr_android:fastScrollEnabled) if its ListView.

Comment: That was one of the solutions we discussed, but nobody was a big fan of it. (But yes, it's a `ListView`)

Comment: @balpha then I am looking forward for the great solution :)

Comment: @balpha Can see tap to answers title to reach top in last update but can't see for Feed/Questions screen.

Comment: It works in the redesigned feed by clicking the time stamp header bar (the one that says "Just now", "Earlier today" or similar). It's not 100% clear whether we'll keep that bar yet, that's why I haven't marked this [meta-tag:status-completed] yet.

Comment: @balpha Ohh I just noticed that bar in current version 0.1.15 !! Great work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think it's been long enough to say that the redesign balpha mentioned which fixes this will stay as it is, so I'm going to mark this as complete.

Comment: Thanks, there is a way to scroll to top!