# Android app crashes while selecting site name

Tags: bug, status-completed, android-app

To reproduce this issue, just start typing in the ***Ask on which site***?.

**Current app version:** 0.1.45

[image]

Comment: Yep,indeed. Repro-d

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Fixed in version 0.1.46 coming out later tonight.

Comment: Yes its fixed in 0.1.46 version!

Comment: Comment testing...just got a crash so...let's see ;)

Comment: Yeh got a crash from last comment, now let me check again ;)

Comment: Oops....let me check again ;)

Comment: Oops add a comment button lost....something weird is happening

Comment: It seems there are many other issues are resolved already. For example: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/193001/how-to-scroll-to-top-in-stack-exchange-android-app , my point is that try to close it if possible.

Answer (score 0):

Here's the stacktrace:

```
10-02 11:51:56.039: E/AndroidRuntime(919): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
10-02 11:51:56.039: E/AndroidRuntime(919): android.view.InflateException: [v0.1.45] Binary XML file line #44: Error inflating class android.widget.ImageButton
10-02 11:51:56.039: E/AndroidRuntime(919):  at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:620)
10-02 11:51:56.039: E/AndroidRuntime(919):  at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneLayoutInflater.onCreateView(PhoneLayoutInflater.java:56)
10-02 11:51:56.039: E/AndroidRuntime(919):  at android.view.LayoutInflater.onCreateView(LayoutInflater.java:669)
10-02 11:51:56.039: E/AndroidRuntime(919):  at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:694)
10-02 11:51:56.039: E/AndroidRuntime(919):  at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:755)
10-02 11:51:56.039: E/AndroidRuntime(919):  at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:492)
10-02 11:51:56.039: E/AndroidRuntime(919):  at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:397)
10-02 11:51:56.039: E/AndroidRuntime(919):  at com.stackexchange.marvin.ui.site.AllSitesArrayAdapter.getView(AllSitesArrayAdapter.java:100)
10-02 11:51:56.039: E/AndroidRuntime(919):  at android.widget.AbsListView.obtainView(AbsListView.java:2177)
10-02 11:51:56.039: E/AndroidRuntime(919):  at android.widget.ListPopupWindow$DropDownListView.obtainView(ListPopupWindow.java:1196)
10-02 11:51:56.039: E/AndroidRuntime(919):  at android.widget.ListView.measureHeightOfChildren(ListView.java:1247)
10-02 11:51:56.039: E/AndroidRuntime(919):  at android.widget.ListPopupWindow.buildDropDown(ListPopupWindow.java:1123)
10-02 11:51:56.039: E/AndroidRuntime(919):  at android.widget.ListPopupWindow.show(ListPopupWindow.java:532)
10-02 11:51:56.039: E/AndroidRuntime(919):  at android.widget.AutoCompleteTextView.showDropDown(AutoCompleteTextView.java:1096)
10-02 11:51:56.039: E/AndroidRuntime(919):  at com.stackexchange.marvin.ui.common.StronglyTypedAutoComplete.showDropDown(StronglyTypedAutoComplete.java:109)
10-02 11:51:56.039: E/AndroidRuntime(919):  at android.widget.AutoCompleteTextView.updateDropDownForFilter(AutoCompleteTextView.java:971)
10-02 11:51:56.039: E/AndroidRuntime(919):  at android.widget.AutoCompleteTextView.onFilterComplete(AutoCompleteTextView.java:953)
10-02 11:51:56.039: E/AndroidRuntime(919):  at com.stackexchange.marvin.ui.common.StronglyTypedAutoComplete.onFilterComplete(StronglyTypedAutoComplete.java:79)
10-02 11:51:56.039: E/AndroidRuntime(919):  at android.widget.Filter$ResultsHandler.handleMessage(Filter.java:285)
10-02 11:51:56.039: E/AndroidRuntime(919):  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
10-02 11:51:56.039: E/AndroidRuntime(919):  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
10-02 11:51:56.039: E/AndroidRuntime(919):  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5103)
10-02 11:51:56.039: E/AndroidRuntime(919):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
10-02 11:51:56.039: E/AndroidRuntime(919):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:525)
10-02 11:51:56.039: E/AndroidRuntime(919):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:737)
10-02 11:51:56.039: E/AndroidRuntime(919):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:553)
10-02 11:51:56.039: E/AndroidRuntime(919):  at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
10-02 11:51:56.039: E/AndroidRuntime(919): Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
10-02 11:51:56.039: E/AndroidRuntime(919):  at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.constructNative(Native Method)
10-02 11:51:56.039: E/AndroidRuntime(919):  at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:417)
10-02 11:51:56.039: E/AndroidRuntime(919):  at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:594)
10-02 11:51:56.039: E/AndroidRuntime(919):  ... 26 more
10-02 11:51:56.039: E/AndroidRuntime(919): Caused by: android.content.res.Resources$NotFoundException: Resource is not a Drawable (color or path): TypedValue{t=0x2/d=0x7f01004c a=-1}
10-02 11:51:56.039: E/AndroidRuntime(919):  at android.content.res.Resources.loadDrawable(Resources.java:2063)
10-02 11:51:56.039: E/AndroidRuntime(919):  at android.content.res.TypedArray.getDrawable(TypedArray.java:601)
10-02 11:51:56.039: E/AndroidRuntime(919):  at android.view.View.<init>(View.java:3364)
10-02 11:51:56.039: E/AndroidRuntime(919):  at android.widget.ImageView.<init>(ImageView.java:121)
10-02 11:51:56.039: E/AndroidRuntime(919):  at android.widget.ImageButton.<init>(ImageButton.java:87)
10-02 11:51:56.039: E/AndroidRuntime(919):  at android.widget.ImageButton.<init>(ImageButton.java:83)
10-02 11:51:56.039: E/AndroidRuntime(919):  ... 29 more
```

Looks like an XML layout has an `attr` resource identifier where a `drawable` is expected.

Comment: Why do I keep using `?selectableItemBackground`... thanks!